# Understanding iotop (DTT) output in Solaris

Tags: mysql, solaris, zfs, opensolaris, dtrace

When running DTT iotop on a write heavy Solaris 10 server, which runs multiple zones with MySQL daemons installed, I get the following output:

```
  UID    PID   PPID CMD              DEVICE  MAJ MIN D            BYTES
   70  26636      1 mysqld           sd1      10  64 R           360448
   70  25940      1 mysqld           sd1      10  64 R           530432
    0      5      0 zpool-rpool      sd1      10  64 W         17250816
```

What bothers me here is the fact that `zpool-rpool` takes up most of the io. What can I do to see which of the MySQL or other processes really takes up the IO - a more elaborate breakdown? If `zpool-rpool` represents "writes to ZFS", then iotop is really not helping me here... :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find Brendan Gregg's recent [blog series on filesystem latency](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/05/24/file-system-latency-part-4/) useful. He shows a couple of scripts for investigating filesystem usage with the syscall provider (which should be more reliable for identifying the responsible processes than the io provider used by iotop).

For example, the `syscall-read-zfs.d` script shown in Part 4 could easily be modified to probe on writes and aggregate on pid rather than execname.

The output of this script may also be more useful than iotop because it shows the number of IOs and the distribution of IO latency per process. For a database, the latency of reads and synchronous writes are direct measures of performance pain - much easier to interpret than bytes per second.

If you have time, I also highly recommend watching his [presentation at BayLISA](http://vimeo.com/24027602) for a hands-on demonstration of how he goes about investigating MySQL query performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure which applications are reading/writing the most, you want to measure at the syscall level. At the device level it's only kernel threads doing their work.